# Cant scanf '-' or '+' in char array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, char

I am doing homework to school. Task is to make program in C that can do some simple things with matrixes like *, -, +.

My program is reading matrixes and save them to int array. When the matrix input ended, I scanf to char to know what operation iam going to do with the matrixes. Operation are stores in char array. (on input can be up to 100 matrixes so 99 operations in between). If user writes *  everything is okay, BUT when user writes '-' or '+' it stores '/n'. I was googling and debuging but still dont know why this happens. Any suggustions are welcome.

User input looks like this: First line is size of matrix.

> 2 3
>
> 76 98 -31
>
> 30 30 32
>
> -
>
> 2 3
>
> 89 25 38
>
> 1 -32 -38

```
    int* readMatrix(int width, int height, char arrayOperation[], int numberOfMatrix, int*err)
    {
    int sizeOfMatrix = ((height*width) + 3), i = 0;
    char operation = 'n';
    int *arrayMatrix = malloc(sizeOfMatrix* sizeof(int));
    arrayMatrix[0] = width;
    arrayMatrix[1] = height;
    for (i = 2; i <= sizeOfMatrix; i++)
    {
           if (i == sizeOfMatrix)
           {
                   if (scanf_s("%c", &operation) != EOF)
                   {
                           if (operation == '*' || operation == '-' || operation == '+')
                           {
                                  arrayOperation[numberOfMatrix] = operation;
                           }
                           else
                           {
                                  *err = 100;
                           }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    arrayOperation[numberOfMatrix] = 'n';
                    break;
                    }
            }
            else if (scanf_s("%d", &(arrayMatrix[i])) == 1)
            {
                      *err = 0;
            }
    }
    return arrayMatrix;
    }
```

In case of * the var operation==*,but in -,+ operation==/n. I call this function in loop, output array is stored in array of int**.

Comment: Don't use `scanf_s` unless your school requires you to. It's not a standard C function, it's a Microsoft extension. `scanf` is standard C.

Comment: Normally i use terminal in linux to compile run and debug. But this time i wasnt sure what is the problem so i use VS to debug. So take it as it is "scanf".

Comment: There is the evil `scanf_s()` and `scanf()` - avoid them - they are not your friends.  When reading _lines_ of input, use the good `fgets()`.  Then code can `sscanf()` the line in many ways, looking for numbers, `-`, etc.

Comment: @DUman `scanf_s` is specified in the C11 standard Annex K.3.5.3.4

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%c"` reads the very next character without skipping any whitespace, so it will store whatever is after the last thing read -- usually a newline.  If you want to skip whitespace, add a space to the format:

```
scanf(" %c", &operation)
```

this will skip any whitespace and store the next non-whitespace character.

You don't need this with `%d` as all of the conversion patterns *except* `%c` and `%[` skip whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

I was discusing this particular problem with my lecturer.

I understand this: when scanf reading the number it jumps over whitespace and /n.

So reading "32/n - " results in reading everything. When reading "32/n * " it stops at "*" because its not sign of any number. So its behave little stupid.

This can solve using fgets() function and read it by char.